# Normalization 3NF and BCNF

Tags: database, normalization

If I have the following relation R = (A, B, C, D)

And the functional dependencies:

- A -> B,   B -> A,  CDB -> A,   CDA -> B

The candidate keys are **CDA** and **CDB**.

The third normal form says that there can not be a functional dependency between non-prime attributes. A non-prime attribute is an attribute that doesn't occur in one of the candidate keys. Then that means that this relation already is 3NF since both A and B, that depend on each other, are part of one of the candidate keys, am I right?

If so, I have another question about BCNF. BCNF says that every determinant must be a candidate key. In this case, A and B are not candidate keys, so that violates BCNF, or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have relation 1-1 between A and B. Then you can make it appart in another table.

You have then 2 relations R1 = (A, B) and R2 = (A, C, D) or R2 = (B, C, D).

You choose between A and B to make attribute of R2. This choice will depend on the attribute size and fetch complexity. For example indexing integers is better than strings.

Comment: Yeah, but in which normal form is this? Since both A and B are included in one of the candidate keys, then they are not non-prime attributes, which means that it has to be in 2NF and 3NF since they deal with non-prime attributes. However, BCNF is more interesting because it's about determinants and that every determinant must be a candidate key. In this case neither A or B is a candidate key. Could you put this more in in the context of normal forms?

Comment: @user1062704 Remove either A or B from the relationship, into their own relationship (table).  Until you do you are have 2NF.